# For Dragon Age: Inquisition, how do I move my old save files from one system to another?

Tags: pc, ps3, dragon-age-inquisition

I am going to buy the game soon, and I am wondering if there is any way I can load the game files that are currently on my older PC? I am thinking about getting Dragon Age: Inquisition on my PS3 as my computers are not strong enough, any more, for such a game.  Is there anyway of getting those saved files from my old PC to my PS3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to migrate PC save files to the PS3.

Even so, Dragon Age: Inquisition does not import save games from previous editions, which is what I believe you're trying to do.  You can log into the [Dragon Age Keep](https://dragonagekeep.com/) using an Origin login that is linked to your PS3 account and fill in the tapestry with the events that occurred in your previous Dragon Age games.  When you play the game on your PS3, you will have the option to import your tapestry and have your old events influence the world in the new game.

Comment: Thanks. I also wanna ask; if I've started the gameplay, can I still upload the tapestry if I made it after I started gaming? Or do I have to start a new one? Thanks a lot for answers and understanding!

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are only asked if you want to import a custom world, when you start a new game.