# Is it possible to transfer my saved games from Xbox 360 to Xbox One?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I've been playing Dragon Age Inquisition on Xbox 360, but now I have an Xbox One (thanks, Santa!), and I'm considering rebuying the game to play it on the current generation console with better graphics.

Is it possible to transfer my current saves from the 360 to One? If so, how? Would just enabling cloud storage on both consoles do the trick?

To be clear, I'm not talking about importing saves from previous Dragon Age games. I'm hoping to find out if I can continue my current Inquisition playthrough on Xbox One or if I'm locked into finishing it on the 360 before I spend money on another copy of the game.

Comment: I thought I had read that you could play save files across generations of the same console family, but now I can't find it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going ahead and trying it. I put them on the cloud drive on the 360, but the Xbox One version of Dragon Age didn't see/didn't have access to them.

So the verdict is... no, it is not possible to post saved games from Xbox 360 to Xbox One.

Comment: There's a request for this feature on [xbox uservoice](https://xbox.uservoice.com/forums/251646-apps/suggestions/8438179-xbox-360-gamesaves-to-xbox-one)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are trying to is import saved games from other editions? (Pleae clarify if I am mistaken) However, such an act is not supported when it comes to Dragon Age: Inquisition.

I think that you might be confusing it with another feature: [The Keep.](https://dragonagekeep.com/en_US/) Using "The Keep" you can transfer saved data from previous **Dragon Age Titles** to slightly influence your gameplay in Dragon Age: Inquisition.

I believe that this question has been asked before at this [LINK](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192493/for-dragon-age-inquisition-how-do-i-move-my-old-save-files-from-one-system-to).

Comment: No, I'm talking about Inquisition saved games. I have a game in progress (about 40 hours in), and I'm wondering if I can transfer it to Xbox One or if I'm locked into finishing it on the 360. I edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: @AnnaLear Sorry for that misconception but it works both ways. You can't import the save file from the XBox 360 to Xbox 1

Answer (score 0):

it is possible but you need to have the black emporium and save your character there